# What is the value of Q such that Q|P-1 where P is a prime number?

Tags: factoring, notation

For my crypto assignment, I'm asked to enter a prime P and generate Q such that Q|P-1

Can anyone guide me what is Q|P-1?

Comment: That notation means $Q$ divides $P-1$. In other words, divide $P-1$ by $Q$, is there a remainder, if so then $Q$ does not divide $P-1$, if not then $Q$ divides $P-1$.

Comment: That means that Q divides P-1.

Comment: BTW, there is a very simple answer that works for all primes but one.

Comment: Will the result of q be a prime? or can it be a composite?

Comment: I'm assuming $Q$ should be prime. If that is the exact wording of the problem, then it doesn't sound like it (though if that is the exact wording of the problem, then the problem is strange as $Q=1$ is an answer).

Comment: Assuming this is about generating a finite field with a subgroup of order Q, we usually choose Q first, then choose a r such that P=Q*r+1 with P of appropriate size. Repeat with different Q or r until P is prime. That way you don't need to do any factoring. For Diffie-Hellman we often choose r=2 and vary Q, for signatures fixing Q and varying r can be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means $Q$ divides $P-1$. In other words, $P-1$ is a multiple of $Q$.